# How to protect STUN/TURN server information in JS?

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn

I'm building a WebRTC app and the JS will have the following code (credentials are from example and not real):

```
{
  'iceServers': [
    {
      'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
    },
    {
      'url': 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=udp',
      'credential': 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
      'username': '28224511:1379330808'
    },
    {
      'url': 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=tcp',
      'credential': 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
      'username': '28224511:1379330808'
    }
  ]
}
```

which means that anyone can grab my credentials and use my server for their own needs.

How do I avoid this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common approach is to give out credentials which expire in a couple of hours. This is described in [this draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-uberti-behave-turn-rest-00)

For example the credentials you quote are taken from [this article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/) and they expired on Mon Sep 16 2013 (from `new Date(1379330808 * 1000)`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case I would like to generate credentials for users that will connect in the future and send them a link. They may connect 10, 15 days from now - it varies. The question is how expiration is calculated. Is it from the time they log in to the server + TTL that I provided?

Comment: typically you would generate the STUN/TURN credentials the moment the client connects to the signaling server, not earlier. That is different from the connection token which can have a longer expiration then.